# Catching windows shutdown events using AFX Message maps, handler function is never called

Tags: visual-c++, shutdown, afx, message-map

I have a windows c++ app that I want to gracefully shutdown. Doing my research seems like QueryEndSession EndSession and Powerbroadcast would be the windows events of interest.

So I plugged them into my message map like this

```
    BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CProgView, CFormView)
        
        ON_WM_QUERYENDSESSION()
        ON_WM_ENDSESSION()
        ON_WM_POWERBROADCAST()
    
    END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

And added the functions needed in the .h

```
    afx_msg BOOL OnQueryEndSession();
    afx_msg void OnEndSession(BOOL);
    afx_msg UINT OnPowerBroadcast(UINT, LPARAM);
```

and .cpp

```
    BOOL CProgView::OnQueryEndSession()
    {
        return 0;
    }
    
    void CProgView::OnEndSession(BOOL b)
    {
    
        int x = 1;
    
    }
    
    UINT CProgView::OnPowerBroadcast(UINT nPowerEvent, LPARAM nEventData)
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

But when I try to shutdown, or simulate a shutdown it fails and my breakpoints are not hit.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\App Certification Kit>rmlogotest.exe 5112
```

LOGO Validation FAILED. Unable to shutdown registered process id 5112 with error code 0000015f

```
Debugging Information --
# of Proc/Svcs   : 1
Reboot ReasonCode: 00000000

    Session 1, Pid 5112, Type 1, Status 1 - progName ()
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You receive `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` in the top level window of your app. Is that a `CFormView`?

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dxiv pointed out that these handlers need to be in the top level window, which was correct.